# How to find for the particular value in Object response type

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, object

below is the response I am getting from my back end call.

```
 {     name: 'abc',
       id : '1234',
       emp: 'abc@sample.com'
    }
```

In my UI i want to test if the `emp === abc@sample.com` exist then perform the certain operation, if not show the error message as emp don't exist. If the response is an Array, it would be easy to search for employee. But I am not sure, how to do it for object response.Can anyone help me with this

Comment: You can iterate over the object keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `.` operator on `Object` such as

`response.emp` returns value of `emp` property in `response` object.

This will work!

```js
var response = {
  name: 'abc',
  id: '1234',
  emp: 'abc@sample.com'
}

if (!response.emp) throw new Error('emp does not exist!')

if (!response.emp === 'abc @sample.com') throw new Error('emp "abc @sample.com" does not exist!')
```